# centering a bitmap in a view with matrix transformation

Tags: android, android-canvas

its driving me mad, i try to center a bitmap in a view using a matrix transformation
and it refuses to work, i searched what type of data you feed postTranslate, but can't find anything about it... i naively assumed it were oiuxels, but it obviously isn't the case...

here's my code:

```
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) 
{
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    viewWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
    viewHeight = getMeasuredHeight();
    screenCenter = new Point(viewWidth / 2, viewHeight / 2);
    Log.d(TAG,"ViewWidth "+viewWidth+","+viewHeight+" cent "+ screenCenter);
    Bitmap map = hexgrid.getMap();
    Point moveTo = new Point(screenCenter.x - map.getWidth()/2,
                             screenCenter.y - map.getHeight()/2);
    Log.d(TAG,"map "+map.getWidth()+","+map.getHeight()+" trans "+moveTo);
    moveTo = new Point(323,140);
    mapTransform.postTranslate(moveTo.x,moveTo.y);
```

}

the calculus for the left upper corner gives me 419,53, but the optically correct values 
would be 323,140 and i don't see the relation between what i computed and what i tested out...

so what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

ok, this is very strange, and if someone has an answer to that i take it, moving the Matrix mapTransform to the onDraw method instead of onMeasure solved the problem....

now i use up CPU cycles for nothing, but at least it works....